# METRIC.EB Error in .local(x, ...) : RasterLayer has no NA cells (for which to compute a distance)

Tags: r, raster

I am stuck on the Energy Balance calculation of the water package. The example code I am following is at this website https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/water/vignettes/Landsat8.html. I am using my own data and am able to read both my original landsat image and the surface reflectance image with my area of interests (aoi). I get the following error when I use this code.

```
Energy.Balance <- METRIC.EB(image.DN = image, image.SR = image.SR,
                        plain=TRUE, aoi=aoi, n = 5, WeatherStation = WeatherStation, 
                        ETp.coef = 1.2, sat="L8", alb.coeff = "Olmedo", LST.method = "SW", 
                        LAI.method = "metric2010", Z.om.ws = 0.03, MTL = MTLfile)


Error in .local(x, ...):RasterLayer has no NA cells (for which to compute a distance)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem when searching for the anchor pixels. Can you try updating to the lastest version of water package (0.7) and adding `anchors.method = 'flexible'` to function `METRIC.EB()`?

Comment: I gave this a try and it is not working. I get the same error message. Not sure if it is related to the code to prepare the DEM, as when I try to access and download the DEM EarthExplorer states "No products are available for this scene." "You need 2 1deg x 1deg SRTM grids"
"http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/download/options/8360/SRTM1N42W0113V3/"
"http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/download/options/8360/SRTM1N43W0113V3/"

Comment: but you said you are getting the same error without using the DEM? Can you try with plain = TRUE?